# How to get form data when the method is GET

Tags: symfony

I have a form search and the method must be 'GET' . The problem is that when I **use GET** I can't access to the fields data in the controller but if I use method POSt I can access to form filds data.

This the action in the controller:

```
public function rechercheAction(Request $request)
{
 //....
$form = $this->createForm(BaseRechercheType::class);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        $titre = $form->get('titre')->getData();
        $date = $form->get('date')->getData();
        $contenue = $form->get('contenue')->getData();
        $publier = $form->get('publier')->getData();

        $qb = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Actualite')->listeRechercheBackend($titre, $date, $contenue, $publier);

        $entities = $paginator->paginate($qb, $request->query->get('page', 1), 10);
    }
  //.....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried routing annotation like so:

```
/**
 * @Route("/recherche")
 * @Method({"GET","POST"})
 */
public function rechercheAction(Request $request)
{
```

Or also in the routing.yml file:

```
# app/config.routing.yml
recherche:
    path:     /recherche
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Controller:recherche }
    methods:  [GET]
```

For the above "AppBundle:Controller:recherche", you should change 'Controller' to what you use. It might be different.

Try those.

Answer (score 0):

By default handleRequest method looks for a POST parameters to process submitted form. So you need to set HTTP method to GET in a form type class.

```
class BaseRechercheType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->setMethod('GET');

        // ...
    }
}
```